# Embedded Jetty rewrites not working properly

Tags: url-rewriting, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to implement a simple rewrite rule in an embedded Jetty server, following the Jetty documentation examples.

I want requests to `/admin/` to rewrite to /admin.html.
At the moment if I request `/admin/` I get a 404 error with `/admin.html` not found.
But if I request `/admin.html` directly, it works!

There are 2 other similar posts on stackoverflow but no answers to the question!

Here's the code:

```java
WebAppContext _ctx = new WebAppContext();
_ctx.setContextPath("/");
_ctx.setDefaultsDescriptor(JETTY_DEFAULTS_DESCRIPTOR);
_ctx.setParentLoaderPriority(true);       
_ctx.setWar(getShadedWarUrl());
_ctx.setResourceBase(getShadedWarUrl());

RewriteHandler rewriter = new RewriteHandler();
rewriter.setRewritePathInfo(true);
rewriter.setRewriteRequestURI(true);
rewriter.setOriginalPathAttribute("requestedPath");

RewritePatternRule admin = new RewritePatternRule();
admin.setPattern("/admin/");
admin.setReplacement("/admin.html");
admin.setTerminating(true); // this will stop Jetty from chaining the rewrites
rewriter.addRule(admin);

_ctx.setHandler(rewriter);

HandlerCollection _handlerCollection = new HandlerCollection();
_handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {_ctx});
server.setHandlers(_result);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace the 2 lines ...

```java
_ctx.setHandler(rewriter);
_handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {_ctx});
```

with

```java
rewriter.setHandler(_ctx);
_handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] {rewriter});
```

That will make the rewriter rules kick in *before* the normal context handling.

Think of the context handling as a tree.  In your example code you have ....

```
server
+--  HandlerCollection
     [0]-- WebAppContext
           +-- Your servlets and filters in web.xml
           +-- DefaultServlet
               +-- RewriteHandler
```

That means if the `WebAppContext` can't handle the request, then the `RewriteHandler` is executed to see if it can handle the request.  That will never happen, as `WebAppContext` is setup to use `DefaultServlet` if nothing else matches.

The simple change suggested changes the tree to look like this ...

```
server
+--  HandlerCollection
     [0]-- RewriteHandler
           +-- WebAppContext
               +-- Your servlets and filters in web.xml
               +-- DefaultServlet
```

This will allow the `RewriteHandler` to do its thing before the `WebAppContext` is even asked.

Note: you can also have your code utilize the `HandlerCollection` a bit more properly for this scenario as well.

```java
// _ctx.setHandler(rewriter);
// rewriter.setHandler(_ctx);
_handlerCollection.setHandlers(new Handler[] { rewriter, _ctx });
```

This will result in the following tree

```
server
+--  HandlerCollection
     [0]-- RewriteHandler
     [1]-- WebAppContext
           +-- Your servlets and filters in web.xml
           +-- DefaultServlet
```