# need to setting multiple handlers according to some business logic

Tags: java, html, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am new to jetty, and I am trying to forward HTML5's FileSystem API calls to client as an when they are received from a JRE, it is an ambitious project to build a Web File System. so far a single handler can deliver a java script page with say a call for the last modified date of a file. I want to be able to call different handlers that will delivers java script like getFilesize, getFileName, etc. so how do I go about having a single jetty server execute different handler on an ad-hoc basis?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple Jetty Handlers is possible, as the Handler metaphor is a just a Tree of Handlers.

See prior answer to question [Embedded Jetty rewrites not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14468007/775715) for some details on how this works.

For a more concrete example, check out the [ManyHandlers embedded jetty example](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/ManyHandlers.java).